# Does google or-tools support incremental SAT solving?

Tags: or-tools

I wonder whether Google or-tools support [incremental SAT solving](https://satcompetition.github.io/2020/track_incremental.html)?

> Many applications of SAT are based on solving a sequence of incrementally generated SAT instances. In such scenarios the SAT solver is invoked multiple times on the same formula under different assumptions. Also the formula is extended by adding new clauses and variables between the invocations. It is possible to solve such problem by solving the incrementally generated instances independently, however this might be very inefficient compared to an incremental SAT solver, which can reuse knowledge acquired while solving the previous instances (for example the learned clauses).

Comment: Imho, internally incremental sat is used *extensively*. I'm guessing the SAT-core brings everything you need to do incremental SAT, although i would think there is no direct ipasir-interface support. As CP-SAT has tons of modes, a lot of *just working functionality* like core-guided max-sat already does this complex stuff for you automatically. In terms of manual incremental ipasir-like usage on some CP-SAT model (extension of SAT), i doubt it's easy to do right now.I think the core-developer confirmed this to me [here](https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/n8u8yoF4UOI/m/EaLoDs-bAQAJ)

Comment: Thanks. I finally got to use IPASIR on some other solvers, which gives you more control.